# Updating Image when the selection in ListBox changes - WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, imagesource

What I am trying to achieve is change the source of Image when I change the selection in Listbox. 
I have a method called **GetImageLink** that fetches a web URL for the current selection and assigns it to **ReferenceImageLink** property. (I checked, link is updated when selection changes). But when I try to use this as a source for the Image it does nothing. The image is perpetually blank from start. Can someone please point me in the right direction? I am new to WPF so it is kind of a little confusing to me.

```
public static string ReferenceImageLink { get; set; }

        private async void VariantListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            ReferenceImageLink = null;
            var selecteditem = sender as ListBox;
            string item = selecteditem.SelectedItem as string;
            await GetImageLink(item);


            BitmapImage referenceBMP = new BitmapImage();
            referenceBMP.BeginInit();

            //ReferenceImageLink property changes as ListBox selection change, GetImageLink takes care of it.
            referenceBMP.UriSource = new Uri(ReferenceImageLink, UriKind.Relative);
            referenceBMP.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
            referenceBMP.EndInit();
            ReferenceImageBox.Source = referenceBMP;

        }
```

```
<Image Name="ReferenceImageBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="189" Margin="558,51,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="230" />
```

[Screenshot of the WPF app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Aa6J.jpg)

Comment: Is the value assigned to ReferenceImageLink a relative path? Can you post a value for ReferenceImageLink here? You can change the UriKind to Absolute if the path is a complete file location.

Comment: Thanks for catching that. I completely missed it. Path was supposed to be absolute. 
Changing it to absolute solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

making **UriKind.Absolute** solved my problem. Thanks

```
referenceBMP.UriSource = new Uri(ReferenceImageLink, UriKind.Absolute);
```